# Laravel mass-assignment insert new record create() alternative?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

I have a 'users' table and 'activation_tokens' table. I have a relation in User model as hasOne(ActivationToken::class);

This is all working fine. Now I want to create a token when creating a user. So I call

```
$user->ActivationToken()->create(array('token'=>'RANDOM_STRING"));
```

This is all good, but I am hitting the mass-assignment error. I *do not* want to set 'token' as fillable.

Instead I try

```
    $activationToken = new ActivationToken();
    $activationToken->token = 'RANDOM_STRING";
    $activationToken->save();
```

Which is ok but it does not set the user_id field in query. I guess I could do it manually by setting `$activationToken->user_id = $user->id;` But this feels wrong since the ORM should be handling this automatically as far as documentation seems to advertise. So I think I am doing something wrong?

I couldn't figure out how to do this correctly. Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to go _ORM way_ then you need to set token to in you `fillable` array for mass-assignment. Otherwise you need to set it manually with the not preferred method `$activationToken->user_id = $user->id`. Two ways you can go. Why don't you want to set the field to `fillable`?

Comment: If I have to set everything fillable to be able to use ORM way, doesnt it defeat the purpose of the fillable/guarded? Unless this whole mass assignment is a flawed concept? Who would assign all values from a random http request to a database query anyway. :)
Wouldn't it be cleaner to just make a function in ActivationToken class which takes an argument user_id and inserts the token? Then I could just call ActivationToken::inserToken($user->id) and be done with it.

Comment: @codedge please see the answer I posted. There seem to be a way to update the table with mass-assignment without adding columns to fillable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after searching the web quite a bit I found out that I can stop mass-assignment restrictions temporarily.

```
    ActivationToken::unguard();
    $user->ActivationToken()->create(array('token'=>str_random(100)));
    ActivationToken::reguard();
```

So this seems to work fine. Also jsphpl's response was quite nice and the solution below is working fine too.

```
    $activationToken = new ActivationToken();
    $activationToken->token = str_random(100);
    $activationToken->user()->associate($user);
    $activationToken->save();
```

Of course some questions remain.

1- Why is

```
$activationToken->user()->associate($user);
```

better than

```
$activationToken->user_id = $user->id;
```

2- Once the unguard line executed:

```
ActivationToken::unguard();
```

Are there any way that the table can be abused before reguard() is called by another PHP process? Note: I am guessing it effects the running process only so in my case it should be safe perhaps...

Anyway, these are outside of the scope of the original question so...

Thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit more orm-ish:

```
...
$activationToken->user()->associate($user);
$activationToken->save();
```

`$activationToken->user()` is the name of the relation pointing to the User model. Note the `()`!

Comment: I have the user() relation with belongsTo in ActivationToken model
However I think attach() does not work with hasOne() and belongsTo() perhaps? I get error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()" and my IDE says "Method 'attach' not found in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo"

Comment: You're right, should be `associate($user)` then, instead of `attach`. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, associate does it. But I dont quite understand what would be the advantage compared to $activationToken->user_id = $user->id; ?
Meanwhile, I found a better solution I think. I will update my post.

Comment: Great. Updated the answer. Technically no advantage, `associate` does exactly the same. Just slightly improved readability, and maybe less of the mentioned *wrong feeling*. But that's both subjective.